# Cardinality of Basis of Infinite Dimensional Vector Space over Countable Field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

This is question 12 from Dummit and Foote Exercises 11.1.

I need to show that for an infinite dimensional vector space $V$ over a countable field $\mathbb F$, any basis $\mathcal B$ of $V$ and $V$ both have the same cardinality. I tried to do it by showing that there exist two injections between $\mathcal B$ to $V$ and $V$ to $\mathcal B$. The former is trivial but I am stuck on how to construct the latter, hence this question.

Comment: Are you familiar with the basic properties of cardinal arithmetic?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was thinking it is kind of intuitively true as I can write $V$ as direct sum of $\mathbb{F}b$ where $b$ ranges over all $\mathcal{B}$ but I can't formulate my argument more rigorously (It seems we are multiplying cardinalities of $\aleph_0$ or less from $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ here which should kind of give the cardinality of $\mathcal{B}$ back, but I don't know how true this is as I have not learned cardinal arithmetic).

Comment: The statement of the question is almost a restatement of "$A$ is an infinite set, $B$ is a countably infinite set $\implies$ $A\times B$ and $A$ have the same cardinality". For a proof you may look at Hungerford's *Algebra*, Theorem 8.11 in prerequisite. (In *Algebra* the fact is stated using cardinality.)

Comment: @Asigan: I like your argument as it is true but I would still like to see a more constructive proof where we construct a bijection between $V$ and $\mathcal{B}$ to prove this statement.

Comment: @ArchisLikhitkar Well, I can either come up with a constructive proof. If your focus is on the constructive proof of $\aleph_0\times \alpha=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal number, then you should delete the vector space part to make it clearer, or post another question asking constructive proof for $\aleph_0\times \alpha=\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is an infinite cardinal number (*but after you searched the site*).